# Zip each file instead of entire directory in c#

Tags: c#, zip

I have a console app that generates multiple pdf. What I want is to convert those individual pdf to zip files. I used ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory but it zips all file from the directory. Is there a way that I can zip every pdf that is being generated.

Update : The code below does what I need based on Zakk's answer.

```
static void pdfandzip()
    {
        //Get the data from database into datatable
        string strQuery = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["sql"];
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
        DataTable dt = GetData(cmd);
        int i = 1;

        foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
        {
            Document document = new Document();

            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream("M://EmpsheetUpload/Pdf/Empsheet" + i + ".pdf", FileMode.Create));

            document.Open();
            iTextSharp.text.Font font5 = iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 5);

            PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(dt.Columns.Count);


            PdfPRow row = null;
            /*float[] widths = new float[] { 4f, 4f, 4f, 4f, 4f };

            table.SetWidths(widths);

            table.WidthPercentage = 100; */
            int iCol = 0;
            string colname = "";
            PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("EmpSheet"));

            cell.Colspan = dt.Columns.Count;

            foreach (DataColumn c in dt.Columns)
            {

                table.AddCell(new Phrase(c.ColumnName, font5));

            }


            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                table.CompleteRow();
                table.AddCell(new Phrase(r[0].ToString(), font5));
                table.AddCell(new Phrase(r[1].ToString(), font5));
                table.AddCell(new Phrase(r[2].ToString(), font5));
                table.AddCell(new Phrase(r[3].ToString(), font5));
                table.AddCell(new Phrase(r[4].ToString(), font5));
                table.AddCell(new Phrase(r[5].ToString(), font5));
                table.AddCell(new Phrase(r[6].ToString(), font5));
            }

            document.Add(table);
            document.Close();
            //ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(@"M://EmpsheetUpload/Pdf", @"M://EmpsheetUpload/Zip/Empsheet" + i + ".zip");     
            string myPath = @"M:\\EmpsheetUpload\Pdf";
            var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(myPath);
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                var filename = file.Split('\\').Last();
                var folderName = filename.Substring(0, filename.IndexOf("."));
                if (Directory.Exists($@"M:\\EmpsheetUpload\Zip1"))
                    Directory.CreateDirectory($@"M:\\EmpsheetUpload\Zip");
                if (File.Exists($@"M:\\EmpsheetUpload\Pdf\Empsheet"+i+".pdf"))
                    File.Copy(file, $@"M:\\EmpsheetUpload\Zip\Empsheet" + i + ".pdf");
                if (File.Exists($@"M:\\EmpsheetUpload\Zip\Empsheet" + i + ".pdf"))
                    ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory($@"M:\\EmpsheetUpload\Zip", $@"M:\\EmpsheetUpload\Zip1\Empsheet"+i+".zip");
                Directory.Delete($@"M:\\EmpsheetUpload\Zip", true);
                i++;
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: You have 

                if (Directory.Exists($@"M:\\EmpsheetUpload\Zip1"))
                    Directory.CreateDirectory($@"M:\\EmpsheetUpload\Zip");

Change Exists to remove the "1" from Zip1

Comment: If you pay attention to the formatting i posted, I included the brackets {} which let you inline write variables to a string. This will keep your paths from getting jumbled. Also, on File.Exists, you have a following File.Copy. There should be a File.Delete to remove the existing file before copying

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use a Directory.EnumerateFiles and loop over each file. Directory.CreateDirectory(fileName_WITHOUT_EXTENSION) and copy the file. Then zip THAT directory and clean up your folders.

In your project add a reference to System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll

This removes the need to install an external library

Here's a working example

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string myPath = @"C:\MYFILES";
        var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(myPath);
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            var filename = file.Split('\\').Last();
            var folderName = filename.Substring(0, filename.IndexOf("."));
            if (Directory.Exists($@"{myPath}\{folderName}"))
                Directory.Delete($@"{myPath}\{folderName}", true);
            Directory.CreateDirectory($@"{myPath}\{folderName}");
            if (File.Exists($@"{myPath}\{folderName}\{filename}"))
                File.Delete($@"{myPath}\{folderName}\{filename}");
            File.Copy(file, $@"{myPath}\{folderName}\{filename}" );
            if(File.Exists($@"{myPath}\{folderName}.zip"))
                File.Delete($@"{myPath}\{folderName}.zip");
            ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory($@"{myPath}\{folderName}", $@"{myPath}\{folderName}.zip");
            Directory.Delete($@"{myPath}\{folderName}", true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm sure I was downvoted for not providing an explicit example. I'm not sure if SO is the place to code for people or to explain to people how to code but I provided the solution anyway

Comment: I updated my code above based on your response. It does the thing that I need. The only thing being, the empsheet number is generated weird. I think, I need to change the placing of increment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[ZipArchive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchivemode(v=vs.110).aspx)** class. Below is the example copied from the link

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (FileStream zipToOpen = new FileStream(@"c:\users\exampleuser\release.zip", FileMode.Open))
            {
                using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(zipToOpen, ZipArchiveMode.Update))
                {
                    ZipArchiveEntry readmeEntry = archive.CreateEntry("Readme.txt");
                    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(readmeEntry.Open()))
                    {
                            writer.WriteLine("Information about this package.");
                            writer.WriteLine("========================");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```